# How to determine how a normal Activity/Intent was started or resumed, who called it last?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, accessibility

I would like to 'monitor' the current (top) Activity or the Activity back stack information to determine how the topActivity was last started or resumed.  Look at ActivityManager and equivalent means.

Pre-requisite: I wish to ignore for the moment,  the Activity for Result and using adding any intent flags to intents and get the info as this is purely 'monitoring' and may not be able to change intent flags as this is running as a library or service.  Since I'm monitoring things like 'onRestart', 'onResume' etc. from within the Activity can not be considered.

---

From the perspective of Activity B

Case 1: Activity A calls Activity B - Activity A last called it.

Case 2: Activity A calls Activity B, Activity B calls Activity C, back button on Activity C is press, Activity B is resumed.

Is there a way to monitor how Activity B got called last?

I would like to gleen this information using existing api's, like ActivityManager, looking at the back stack or equivalent since it will be from a library, still looking.